# Create array from multiple strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 strings, these are not real data just an example:

```
string items = "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3";

string price = "300, 400, 500";

string tax = "30, 50, 60";
```

What I am trying to do is create an array like so:

```
[Item 1] => Array([Price] => 300, [Tax] => 30), [Item 2] => Array([Price] => 400, [Tax] => 50), [Item 3] => Array([Price] => 500, [Tax] => 60)
```

the problem is I have no idea how to do this in ASP.NET, if I had to do this in PHP, this would be no problem.

Comment: Why not make a method that you can invoke? This method would take in an array or list as a parameter and then the filter. So, then in your method, you just loop through the array elements of the given array and return a filtered an array to use in your code.

Comment: C# arrays are not associative. It looks like you want a Dictionary (of dictionaries), or perhaps more idiomatically, a list of objects whose type is a class called Item with Name, Price and Tax properties.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Good catch. If the 3 array relate to each other, they shouldn't be 3 separate arrays. Dictionary would be more appropriate.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Besides, what would this have to do with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#, you would probably declare a class like:

```
class Item {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
}
```

And then you could split your strings into arrays and parse them into a list of `Item`:

```
string items = "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3";    
string price = "300, 400, 500"; 
string tax = "30, 50, 60";  

var names = items.Split(',');
var prices = price.Split(',');
var taxes = tax.Split(',');

var list = new List<Item>();

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
    list.Add(new Item() {
        Name = names[i].Trim(),
        Price = decimal.Parse(prices[i]),
        Tax = decimal.Parse(taxes[i])
    });
}
```

The above is pretty brittle: I'm assuming each list has the same number of elements, and there's no handling for parse failures converting the strings to decimal; but you get the idea.

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s3eVNx) that runs the above code.

Comment: if you could use the `for` loop wont it be cleaner? +1